# Is accessing different key/value pairs in associative array simultaneously multi-cpu safe?

Tags: dtrace

From Brendan's post: [DTrace variable types](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/11/25/dtrace-variable-types/), I know accessing associative array simultaneously isn't multi-cpu safe.Is accessing different key/value pairs in associative array simultaneously multi-cpu safe? Or it is also not multi-cpu safe.

Comment: This question is answered by dtrace-discuss mail loop, and the answer is [multi-cpu safe](http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/184261/2014/04/sort/time/page/1/entry/11:12/20140410014249:EB3CCA90-C072-11E3-8189-9F9034AA57AC/).

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, please post it as an answer and accept it so future readers may benefit.  Also, the link in your comment requires logging in; please quote the relevant portions of the linked page in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Adam's answer: "Accessing elements with different tuple keys is safe. Further, thread-local associative arrays are allowed -- though obviously serve a different purpose.". For detailed information, you can refer this link:[http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/184261/2014/04/sort/time/page/1/entry/11:12/20140410014249:EB3CCA90-C072-11E3-8189-9F9034AA57AC/](http://www.listbox.com/member/archive/184261/2014/04/sort/time/page/1/entry/11:12/20140410014249%3aEB3CCA90-C072-11E3-8189-9F9034AA57AC/).